# Is willn't ever used?

Tags: negation, future-tense, contractions

- He *willn't* go there tomorrow.
- He *won't* go there tomorrow.

Do people use **"willn't"** our days?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, no one uses **willn't**. Only **won't** is correct in all major dialects. It's actually a contraction of the earlier **woll not**, but English changed and **will** became more standard, though the contraction stayed.

You *may* find **willn't** in some older texts, but that would have been a conscious decision by the author to buck the standard usage.

Comment: For those interested - the answers under [What is “won't” a contraction of?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/4521) on ELU explain the origin of won't in a little more depth.

Answer (score 2):

No people don't use 'willn't.

It is either 
- will not or
- won't

The short form of 'will not' is 'won't'